# Installing httpssl module on a running NGINX server

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

New to NGINX, we inherited a project that runs Django/FCGI/NGINX on a hosted RHEL box. A requirement has come in that the site now needs to have ssl enabled. Client was pretty sure the person who had built the site had made it so they could use ssl.

I backed up the conf file, added the server block for the ssl instance and tried to reload. Reload failed because it didn't recognize the ssl in this line:

ssl on;

Not an NGINX expert, but the David Caruso in me tells me that the server (sunglasses on) is not secure.

I know that you need to configure NGINX at install with this module. If this didn't happen, how hard/risky is it to reconfigure a running nginx box with this module given that we didn't configure it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that nginx has been compiled with module http_ssl_module:

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | grep ssl
```

> configure arguments: --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ... **--with-http_ssl_module** ...

If no http_ssl_module, install nginx from EPEL.

Comment: thanks, so long story short nginx WILL have to be reinstalled?

Comment: In nginx compile without http_ssl_module, you need reinstall(recompile) nginx.